# How to top a list of pids from a file in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pid

I've a script to get a list of pid's
I want to see cpu usage, memory usage of those pids using top.

I am able to top a list of pid's using:

```
top -p pid1,pid2,pid3
```

I have a function which returns the pid's I need, which I am converting into a comma separated list as follows:

```
$ gal vppoc|cut -d" " -f1|xargs|sed -e 's/ /,/g'
12775,13319,14404,14549,14920,27534
```

However, the following isn't working:

```
gal vppoc|cut -d" " -f1|xargs|sed -e 's/ /,/g'| top -p
```

It gives the error:

```
top: -p argument missing
```

Need some help to get this working - i.e. to be able to top the pid's returned by my function above.

Thanks

Comment: On another note, `sed` in this case can be replaced by `tr` because `tr` should be lightweight compared to `sed`. But even better, `xargs|sed` pipeline can be converted to `paste -s -d,` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `|` (pipe) and it connects stdout of one process to stdin of the other.

What you need is

```
top -p $(your_function_here)
```

for example

```
top -p $(gal vppoc|cut -d" " -f1|xargs|sed -e 's/ /,/g')
```

Comment: oh i see, so is it that top doesn't expect any stdin, so we have to substitute the values in place?

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is a correct solution.
I just give a few lines to understand what was wrong in your command line.
You have given the pids to the top command stdin and not as argument.
It is simple to solve with xargs:

```
gal vppoc|cut -d" " -f1|xargs|sed -e 's/ /,/g'| xargs top -p
```

However it would still not work because the top would have no tty.
This can be solved to run top in batch mode:

```
gal vppoc|cut -d" " -f1|xargs|sed -e 's/ /,/g'| xargs top -b -p
```

It works in batch mode, so you cannot control it, and it has no connection to tty to refresh screen.

To work on tty you should not use the top command through pipe. It is possible to run the command and get the parameter value from an internal command using the way in the previous answer or an other syntax to solve this:

```
top -p `gal vppoc|cut -d" " -f1|xargs|sed -e 's/ /,/g'`
```